# Mac OS internet Recovery mode stuck on progress option with globe animated screen

Tags: macos, recovery, internet

[image]
It’s stuck on here. Anybody knows this answer ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Please see [ask] for tips on asking questions.  This type of issue is well-covered on this site with many good answers already posted.  Have you tried any of them?  Please [edit] your post with steps you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

I was solved it, I just plug/unplug my internet cable from Wifi Router.

Answer (score 0):

There is very little to go on, not your fault.

First stab is that Unix (macOS) networking is very fragile and any DNS problem can cause a bad day. This recovery needs a solid network to use with solid DNS...

Second stab, does your network connection have any firewalls on it that block ports?  I would recommend a wide open for outbound connections network with just a simple Network Address Translator (NAT) setup.